# Junit: how to handle class level variables in junit test cases

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In the below incrementId() method, I need to test *id > MAX_NUM* greater than the condition.

```
pubic class ClassATest {

  AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger (0)
  public static final int MAX_NUM = 1000

  pulic long incrementId() {
   long id = atomicInt.incrementAndGet();
   if (id > MAX_NUM ) {
     System.out.println("need to be tested....")
   }
}
}
```

Is it possible to mock the above atomicInt object? or is there any way to test above  *if condition* without affecting the performance?

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: you *could* add a constructor with the initial value of the atomic as an argument `public ClassATest(int initial) {atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(initial); }` that way you could add a pretty high initial value in the test when creating an instance of `ClassATest`

Comment: Another option would be to make `MAX_NUM` configurable through a constructor.  In either approach, the constructor could be `protected` (assuming the test class has the same package as the class under test).

Comment: Both are useful ways for this case. Thanks a lot. Its worked for me.